# Find oldest account per company in sql

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a few tables that look like the below

Users

```
-----------------------------------------
| id | policyId | createdAt | updatedAt |
-----------------------------------------
| 1  |    1     |  2017/8/5 |  2017/8/5 |
| 2  |    1     |  2016/4/5 |  2017/8/5 |
| 3  |    2     |  2017/7/2 |  2017/8/5 |
| 4  |    2     |  2018/8/5 |  2017/8/5 |
-----------------------------------------
```

Policies

```
------------------------------------------
| id | companyId | createdAt | updatedAt |
------------------------------------------
| 1  |    1      |  2017/8/5 |  2017/8/5 |
| 2  |    2      |  2016/4/5 |  2017/8/5 |
------------------------------------------
```

Companies

```
-----------------------------------------
| id | policyId | createdAt | updatedAt |
-----------------------------------------
| 1  |    2     |  2017/8/5 |  2017/8/5 |
| 2  |    1     |  2016/4/5 |  2017/8/5 |
-----------------------------------------
```

I need to answer the question "What is the id of the user for each company with the oldest account. So the output should look something like this.

Output

```
----------------------------------
| CompanyId | UserId | CreatedAt |
----------------------------------
|     1     |   2    |  2016/4/5 |   
|     2     |   3    |  2017/7/2 |
----------------------------------
```

---

What I have gotten so far looks something like this but I know it is no were near correct.

```
SELECT c.id, MIN(u.createdAt) FROM companies as c
    JOIN policies as p on p.companyId = c.id
    JOIN users as u on u.policyId = p.id
    GROUP BY c.id;
```

This seems to let me get the oldest date for each company user but I am not sure how to correlate the users back to that date to get the user id's. I am thinking the query above might have to be a sub-query but that is about as far as my sql knowledge goes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to join the whole query to itself and join by comapny id and createdAt column.

see demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f4ea7/22

```
SELECT c.id as companyID,
  u.id as userID,
  u.createdAt
FROM companies as c
JOIN policies as p on p.companyId = c.id
JOIN users as u on u.policyId = p.id
JOIN (SELECT c.id as companyID, 
    min(u.createdAt) as min_dt
    FROM companies as c
    JOIN policies as p on p.companyId = c.id
    JOIN users as u on u.policyId = p.id
    GROUP BY c.id) sub
on c.id=sub.companyID 
where u.createdAt=sub.min_dt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.company_id, u.user_id, MIN(u.createdAt) FROM policies p, user_u,
(SELECT min(createdAt) as minDate, policy_id as policyId from users
 GROUP BY policy_id) as sub
WHERE p.id = u.policy_id
AND sub.minDate = u.createdAt
AND sub.policy_id = u.policyId;
```

Answer (score 0):

### It will give u the expected output But some hard coded way

```
SELECT c.id as companyid,u.id as userid, MIN(u.createdAt) as createdAt FROM company as c
    JOIN policies as p on p.cmpid = c.id
    JOIN users as u on u.policyId = p.id
    GROUP BY c.id,u.id order by MIN(u.createdAt) asc limit 2;
```